# python function on pandas df using multiple columns and reset variable

Tags: python, function, pandas, lambda

Whats the best way to do the following in python/pandas please?

I want to count the occurences where trend data 2 steps out of line with trend data 1 and reset the counter each time trend data 1 changes.

I'm struggling with the right way to do it on the dataframe creating a new column `df['D']` in this example.

`df['A']` = trend data 1
 `df['B']` = boolean indicator if trend data 1 changes
 `df['C']` = trend data 2
 `df['D']` = desired result

```
df['A']        df['B']        df['C']        df['D']            
  1                0              1            0
  1                0              1            0
 -1                1             -1            0
 -1                0             -1            0
 -1                0              1            1
 -1                0             -1            1
 -1                0             -1            1
 -1                0              1            2 
 -1                0              1            2
 -1                0             -1            2
  1                1              1            0
  1                0              1            0
  1                0             -1            1
  1                0              1            1
  1                0             -1            2
  1                0              1            2
  1                0              1            2
```

in excel i would simply use:

```
=IF(B2=1,0,IF(AND((C2<>C1),(C2<>A2)),D1+1,D1))
```

however, i've always struggled in not being able to reference prior cells in pandas.

I can't use `np.where()`. I'm sure its just apply a function in the correct way but I can't seem to make it work referencing other columns and resetting the variable.  I've looked at other answers but can't seem to find anything to work in this situation.

something like

- note: create  `df['E'] = df['C'].shift(1)`

`def corrections(x):`

```
    if df['B'] == 1:    
        x = 0
    elif ((df['C'] != df['E']) AND ( df['C'] != df['A'])):
        x = x + 1
    else:
        x
```

apologies, as I feel i'm missing something rather simple with this question but just keep going round in circles!

Comment: Could you edit your question to explain where the first group of 2s is coming from?

Answer (score 0):

```
def make_D (df):

    counter = 0

    array = []

    for index in df.index:

        if df.loc[index, 'A']!=df.loc[index, 'C']:

           counter = counter + 1

        if index>0:

            if df.loc[index, 'B'] != df.loc[index-1, 'B']:

                 counter = 0

        array.append(counter)

    df['D'] = array

    return (df)
```

---

```
new_df = make_D(df)
```

hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
#Set a list to store values for column D
d = []

#calculate D using the given conditions
df.apply(lambda x: d.append(0) if ((x.name==0)|(x.B==1)) else d.append(d[-1]+1) if (x.C!=df.iloc[x.name-1].C) & (x.C!=x.A) else d.append(d[-1]), axis=1)

#set columns D using values from the list d.
df['D'] = d

Out[594]: 
    A  B  C  D
0   1  0  1  0
1   1  0  1  0
2  -1  1 -1  0
3  -1  0 -1  0
4  -1  0  1  1
5  -1  0 -1  1
6  -1  0 -1  1
7  -1  0  1  2
8  -1  0  1  2
9  -1  0 -1  2
10  1  1  1  0
11  1  0  1  0
12  1  0 -1  1
13  1  0  1  1
14  1  0 -1  2
15  1  0  1  2
16  1  0  1  2
```